# Running as many instances of a program as possible

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiple-instances

I'm trying to implement some code to import user's data from another service via the service's API. The way I'm going to set it up is all the request jobs will be kept in a queue which my simple importer program will draw from. Handling one task at a time won't come anywhere close to maxing out any of the computer's resources so I'm wondering what is the standard way to structure a program to run multiple "jobs" at once? Should I be looking into threading or possibly a program that pulls the jobs from the queue and launches instances of the importer program? Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**: What I have right now is in Python although I'm open to rewriting it in another language if need be.

Comment: What I have right now is in python although I'd be open to moving it to something else if it makes a difference.

Comment: What's the bottleneck? Is this really a CPU bound problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Producer-Consumer queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem), with as many Consumer threads as you need to optimize resource usage on the host (sorry - that's very vague advice, but the "right number" is problem-dependent).

If requests are lightweight you may well only need one Producer thread to handle them.

Launching multiple processes could work too - best choice depends on your requirements.  Do you need the Producer to know whether the operation worked, or is it 'fire-and-forget'?  Do you need retry logic in the event of failure? How do you keep count of concurrent Consumers in this model?  And so on.

For Python, take a look at [this](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html).

Comment: Thanks Steve for the reply. No worries I wasn't expecting an exact number of threads etc. What I'm working on is a web service so my plan was to have my service add the jobs to Amazon's SQS (Simple Queuing Service). I'd then have my importer program running on a server pulling from SQS. I do need to ensure the jobs succeed. So are you thinking I should run one instance of the program and have it poll jobs from the queue and just launch a threat for each job up to some set number of threads?

Comment: If you need tight control of the consumers, I think threads will be easier than separate processes. Really it's just two thread types you have after all. That's relatively simple to handle. Java and C# both have builtin queues you can use to connect producer with consumers.